# Do the experience shrines XP bonus go to players nearby?

Tags: diablo-ii

I've been playing Diablo 2 with a friend and every time we run across an experience shrine we check our experience levels and the one with the lowest experience grabs the shrine.

Does this actually matter? Do the experience shrines XP bonus affect only the person that has it or does that bonus also go to players nearby?

Comment: It was quite some time ago I tested this with my friends, I remembered it was something like it affects the exp from the kills made by the person with the shrine bonus, so the person who can kill fastest should take it. Might have remembered wrongly though.

Answer (score 3):

The Shrine has only affect on the person who owns it.
Experience in a party is still a complicated thing. Even if there are other on the server playing and not in your party, monsters grant bonus EXP but they also get stronger.
You gain EXP from party, if you are close by the killed monsters. (ages ago you only had to be in the same area)
The guys who does the killing blow gets more exp than the guy who "watches".

Comment: Can you provide a link for the part about "the killing blow giving more experience"? I couldn't find anything about it in any diablo 2 related wiki or forum.